# Note Duration Priority?

Tags: notation

If a dotted half note precedes a quarter note of the same pitch, is the note held for the duration of the former or latter? Does the following quarter note supersede the dotted half in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That dotted half note is tracked to *a different voice*; it basically is like another melodic line played at the same time as the other voice (the way you can tell is if the stems of the noteheads point away from the center of the staff). The dotted half is played for the entire measure, whereas the other notes are all played in sequence starting at the same time that the dotted half does.

*In the future, for questions like these, it is invaluable to post the time signature of the piece (which I assume to be 3/4).*

Comment: I miss however a quarter rest at the beginning of the bar for the middle voice, which continues with the two quarters of downward stem f (if a treble clef can be assumed).

Comment: It's poorly written, in that it's supposed to be 3(?) voices. However, it's not easy to show 3 voices when stem options allow 2. The 'middle voice' needs a rest at the beginning of the bar. Unless - it's not 3/4 but 6/4, in which case, it's even more badly written!

Comment: It seems to me the two down-stems of the third voice are unnecessary. They seem to be there just to allow the F to be shown as held but in guitar music this can be shown by just using the tie, with no need for a third voice. It's often a matter of taste how these things are notated. The message is clear which is all that matters.

Comment: @PeterJ - had the message been clear, this question wouldn't have appeared!

Comment: I bet the writer just didn't want to take up space writing in that rest. Sucks, but it's common practice. And yes, three voices but weird, right?

Comment: I strongly disagree that the example poorly notated. This sort of figure has been standard in the Western tradition for centuries. Certainly there alternative renderings which that convey the same meaning, but once understood, like anything in traditional Western music notation, the meaning is clear.

Comment: @DeanRansevycz I was in fact very careful not to say that the example was poorly notated. Perhaps you took my "Sucks, but it's common practice" as meaning such? Because if so, that's not what I meant to say.

Comment: Agreed, @user45266; yours are not the comments I’m railing against.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Maybe the reply feature would be useful here* (typing @ and then a user's name to reply to them)*, as I get notified of all comments on my own post, but not the other commenters, who may not have received notice of your remarks.

Comment: @DeanRansevycz - 'once understood....the meaning is clear'. That's true about everything, not just notation! The sole purpose of writing dots is for others to read and thus be able to play what's written. This example is not the best.

Comment: @DeanRansevycz I stand somewhat corrected; apparently Tim somehow saw it :) But it's still a good feature of the site.